# Provisioning Profiles are not being deleted

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I remove the provisioning profiles from my `iPhone` using `XCode 7.2`, they always reappear whenever I reconnect my device.

This is **where** I'm viewing and deleting it: *(the image is merely representative)*

[image]

How can I effectively delete all provisioning profiles from my device?

Answer (score 1):

On you iPhone go to "Settings" > "General" > "Profiles & Device Management". That should bring up a list of the installed profiles.

Tap on the profile you would like to delete.

At the bottom of the profile is a button "Delete Profile". Tap that button and follow the prompts to delete the profile.